# Python 'ndarray' cannot be converted to a MySQL type?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I am relatively new to Python and I am trying to execute the following code:

```
sqlQuery = "UPDATE users SET UserImage = %s, PointOfInterest1X = %s, PointOfInterest1Y = %s, " \
               "PointOfInterest2X = %s, PointOfInterest2Y = %s WHERE Email = %s;"
inputData = (slicedImage, x1, y1, x2, y2, prevEmail)
mycursor.execute(sqlQuery, inputData)
```

But it is giving me the following error when I run it

> "Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err)
>
> > mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'ndarray' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

I don't understand what is going wrong, any help? (x1, x2, y1, y2 are floats and prevEmail is a String)

Comment: What type is `slicedImage`?

Comment: @jjramsey it is an image read through cv2.imread()

Comment: `cv2.imread()` returns an `ndarray`.

Comment: @jjramsey is there any way in which I can save this as a BLOB in a MySQL database in Python?

Comment: Probably, but I don't know how to do that myself.

Comment: @jjramsey Thanks for the information, I'll do some research. Appreciated.